# How to get particular values from database using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Please look at this code first:

```
$dbhost = xxxx;
$dbuser = xxxxxxx;
$dbpass = xxxxxxxxx;
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);

$sql = SELECT week, name, date FROM lucky;
$sqlx = SELECT week, name, date FROM lucky WHERE week = 1;
$sqlxx = SELECT week, name, date FROM lucky WHERE week = 2;
$retval = mysql_query( $sqlx, $conn );

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
  $fetch = $_POST['weekcheck'];
  if($fetch == 1)
  {
    echo "{$row['week']}";
  }
}
```

The value of **weekcheck** in this code is coming from a different page. All I want is, if **$fetch == 1**, then I want to run **$sqlx** and if **$fetch == 2**, then I want to run **$sqlxx**. But in **$retval**, already **$sqlx** is used. Please suggest something.

Comment: Why not use the value straight away in the query itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

havent test this code but it should run, it also sanitizes your weekcheck integer

```
<?php
$dbhost = xxxx;
$dbuser = xxxxxxx;
$dbpass = xxxxxxxxx;
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);

$one_and_only_sql = "SELECT week, name, date FROM lucky".(intval($_POST['weekcheck'])>0)?" WHERE week =".(intval($_POST['weekcheck'])):"";

$retval = mysql_query( $one_and_only_sql, $conn );

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{

    echo "{$row['week']}";

}

?>
```

replying to your comment:

replace the line of $one_and_only_sql with this:

```
$one_and_only_sql = "SELECT week, name, date FROM lucky".(intval($_POST['weekcheck'])>0)?" WHERE week = 'Week ".str_pad(strval(intval($_POST['weekcheck'])), 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT)." 2014'":"";
```

Comment: Hi Sharky. Your code seems interesting. But I do not have values like 1,2,3... for **week** in database. Only **weekcheck** stores 1,2,3... Week has values like: **Week 09 2014**, **Week 10 2014**, **Week 11 2014**...

Hence, this seems invalid in your code: 
        
`WHERE week =".(intval($_POST['weekcheck'])):"";`

Comment: Compiler says unexpected ":"

Comment: @Niks there is no typo in my answer, you must forgot a semicolon somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!empty($_POST['weekcheck'])) // check whether its not blank
    {
       $where = " where `week` =".$_POST['weekcheck'];
    }
    else
    {
       $where = ""; // blank string 
    }

    // so if weekcheck is posted then what ever the value is will pass to the sql query.
    //for e.g. $_POST['weekcheck']=1;
    //then sql statement will be SELECT week, name, date FROM lucky where `week` = 1
    //for e.g. $_POST['weekcheck']=2;
    //then sql statement will be SELECT week, name, date FROM lucky where `week` = 2
    //else if not posted weekcheck
    //then sql statement will be SELECT week, name, date FROM lucky


    $sql = "SELECT week, name, date FROM lucky ".$where;

    $retval = mysql_query( $sqlx, $conn );
```

u got it rom here..! :)

Comment: Hi... Only weekcheck stores 1,2,3... Week has values like: Week 09 2014, Week 10 2014, Week 11 2014...
How will I concatenate ?

Comment: please elaborate your question in brief.

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
$sql = SELECT week, name, date FROM lucky;
$sqlx = SELECT week, name, date FROM lucky WHERE week = 1;
$sqlxx = SELECT week, name, date FROM lucky WHERE week = 2;
$retval = mysql_query( $sqlx, $conn );
$retvalxx = mysql_query( $sqlxx, $conn );

  $fetch = $_POST['weekcheck'];



    if($fetch == 1)
      {
        while($row3 = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_ASSOC))
         {
            //do some thing
         }
      }

    if($fetch == 2)
      {
        while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($retvalxx, MYSQL_ASSOC))
         {
            //do some thing
         }
      }
```